# Building a Weather App with React and I am running into a problem where I need to click a button twice in order to switch units

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

The title was rather vague so I will try to explain in a bit more detail here. I have a button that swaps between imperial and metric units. It changes the params in the API URL and re-renders the component that displays the weather. Now my button to swap from Day Weather to Night Weather works instantly when clicked but I am running into a weird problem where my button that swaps from metric to imperial needs to be double clicked when swapping from imperial to metric. Here's a link to the project if you want to reproduce the bug. Thank you for all the help.

http://react-weather-app-trevinshu.vercel.app/

Code for state calls:

```
 let toggle = false;

  const [displayedWeather, setDisplayedWeather] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [swapUnit, setUnits] = useState(`https://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${key}?apikey=${apiKey}&details=true&metric=true`);
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('metric');
```

Here's my code for the API call:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    //Fetch selected weather forecast
    const displayWeather = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(swapUnit);
      const result = await data.json();
      setDisplayedWeather(result);
    };

    //Timeout to delay display of weather forecast & show loading state
    setTimeout(() => {
      displayWeather();
      toast.success(`Weather for ${city}`, { position: 'top-center', hideProgressBar: true, toastId: customId });
      setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, [swapUnit]);
```

Here's my code for the button function to toggle from metric to imperial and vice versa:

```
 //Toggle between celsius and fahrenheit
  function changeParams(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggle = !toggle;

    if (toggle) {
      setButtonText('Metric');
      setUnits(`https://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${key}?apikey=${apiKey}&details=true&metric=false`);
    } else {
      setButtonText('Imperial');
      setUnits(`https://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${key}?apikey=${apiKey}&details=true&metric=true`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you begin `metric` and `toggle = false` ... when you hit the button, `toggle` becomes true, which sets the units to ... metric .... try `if (!toggle)` instead or set `let toggle = true` at init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time any of your states change you redefine toggle to false
thats how component rendering works to fix the issue you could do something like this:

```
function changeParams(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (buttonText === 'Imperial') {
      setButtonText('Metric');
      setUnits(`https://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${key}?apikey=${apiKey}&details=true&metric=false`);
    } else {
      setButtonText('Imperial');
      setUnits(`https://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/5day/${key}?apikey=${apiKey}&details=true&metric=true`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: *each time any of your states change you redefine toggle to false* - where does this not happen?

Comment: first code block of the question let toggle = false; then some useState() hooks are applied it is for sure in the component function body it also makes sense

Comment: so, why does clicking TWICE work if that's the case?

Comment: yea forgot to say that in answer react is smart enough not to rerender component if the new state and old state are the same trust me I recently wrote 9000 lines of react code I know what Im talking about

Comment: Sure, I don't doubt you know what you're talking about, I just think you're wrong in this case :p

Comment: Thanks. What you suggested worked. Just had adjust the default value for setButtonText call.